# write pandas parquet partitioned into s3

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, airflow

How to write parquet partitioned by column into s3? I'm trying:

```
def write_df_into_s3(df, bucket_name, filepath, format="parquet"):
    buffer = None
    hook = S3Hook()

    if format == "parquet":
        buffer = BytesIO()
        df.to_parquet(buffer, index=False, partition_cols=['date'])
    else:
        raise Exception("Format not implemented!")

    hook.load_bytes(buffer.getvalue(), filepath, bucket_name)

    return f"s3://{bucket_name}/{filepath}"
```

But I got an error `'NoneType' object has no attribute '_isfilestore'`.

Comment: looks like a bug in pyarrow check this jira issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-5156?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

Answer (score 2):

For python 3.6+, AWS has a library called aws-data-wrangler that helps with the integration between Pandas/S3/Parquet

to install do;

```
pip install awswrangler
```

if you want to write your pandas dataframe as a partitioned parquet file to S3, do;

```
import awswrangler as wr
wr.s3.to_parquet(
    dataframe=df,
    path="s3://my-bucket/key/"
    dataset=True,
    partition_cols=["date"]
)
```